# Using variables inline SQL ( MSSQL )

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Possible to do something like this... MSSQL ?

where the @myText variable equals a string of 'id = 5'

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ( @myText )
```

Comment: This is not possible unless you're using dynamic SQL, and even if you do, that's a really, really bad idea, as it's impossible to protect such a thing from SQL Injection.

Comment: Why is this something you want to do? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Chances are you just need to understand how to properly use parameters...

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE MyColumn = @MyVar`? If no then Zohar already gives a short answer.

Comment: We are purging a bunch of tables ie. many delete statements ( with conditions ) on different tables... looking for a way to make the script easier to implement. Right now we have many single commands per table each with the same condition.

Comment: Sounds like a parameter is what you need. `DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID = @id`. Not sure what the application platform is that is generating the statements but almost any "modern" application platform or library will have the ability to create and execute a parameterized sql statement.

Comment: Are you therefore simply looking for pass multiple ID's? If so, have you considered a User Defined Table Type? As `ID` appears to be an integer type, and having a User Defined Table Type which is simply a column of the `int` data type is quite a common "utility" object it would seem like that would be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks guys. Your help led me to the use of 'temporary tables' which helped me solve this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. With your help led me to using temporary tables like so....

```
DECLARE @companies TABLE (comp_code INT)    -- create temporary table
INSERT INTO @companies VALUES (5)           -- ( repeat this line for each additional company you wish to keep )

DELETE FROM tableOne Where (Comp_Code NOT IN (select comp_code from @companies));
DELETE FROM tableTwo Where (Comp_Code NOT IN (select comp_code from @companies));
DELETE FROM tableThree Where (Comp_Code NOT IN (select comp_code from @companies));
-- etc etc
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use dynamic SQL.  In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql  = 'SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ([myText])';

set @SQL = replace(@sql, '[mytext]', @mytext);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain any of the ***huge*** injection problems here. On it's own, this is just a security flaw waiting to be exploited. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also there maybe a relation between those tables, so maybe the best way is `ON DELETE CASCADE` (It depends on the given info, personally I'll let the dynamic sql as a last option)

Comment: Frankly, Gordon, I might have expected such an answer with someone less experienced, but from an expert with your reputation, this answer shouldn't be posted at all, and if you do bother posting this, the least you should do is explain why is it such a terrible idea.